# How to get SAP Hana views list in C# using SAPbobsCOM dll?

Tags: c#, hana, sapb1

Following SAP HANA Query is not executing in C# code. But its working in SAP HANA studio.

Query:

```
SELECT VIEW_NAME,VIEW_TYPE,SCHEMA_NAME FROM VIEWS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'TEST'
```

C# code:

```
public dynamic ExecuteReader(string query) 
{
    SAPbobsCOM.Recordset recSet = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)this.m_CompanyConn.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
    recSet.DoQuery(query);
    return recSet;          
}
```

Error:

> 1). [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;260 invalid
>   column name: VIEW_NAME: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7)

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query works fine on SAP HANA Studio SQL Console,

Maybe you can try following

```
SELECT "VIEW_NAME", "VIEW_TYPE", "SCHEMA_NAME" FROM VIEWS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'SAPABAP1';
```

Comment: Is it possible that you could try "SELECT * ..." without using column names? I wonder if you really can query the VIEWS system view.

Comment: Yes, this query is executing "SELECT * FROM VIEWS", but this query is not working "SELECT * FROM VIEWS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'TEST'"